# Flex 4.5 drag and drop

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4

I need to drag the child component in the parent such a way that the child component can replace the place they have in parent.

eg. If I have a 3 button a,b,c inside a panel and need to movie the position of a,b,c with drag and drop the placement could be b,a,c or c,a,b and so on.

any idea would be appreciated.

thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a spark List.  It has what you want built in.